# Unterschied zwischen „soll es geben“ vs „solle es geben“

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive, modal-verb

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Formulierungen:

„Außerdem **soll** es auch weitere Fehler geben.“ und „Außerdem **solle** es auch einige weitere Fehler geben.“?

Der erste Satz enthält die Subjektive Bedeutung des Verbs „sollen“. Der zweite gelangte zu derselben Bedeutung durch Verwendung von Konjunktiv 1.

Meines Wissens nach kann man die beiden Formen bei Weitergabe einer Information verwenden. Sind sie, mit der Ausnahme von purer indirekten Rede, bei der Konjunktiv 1 verwendet muss, austauschbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch sind beide Varianten tatsächlich fast beliebig austauschbar. Mein persönliches Sprachgefühl macht trotzdem einen kleinen Unterschied:

wenn ich sage „es soll weitere Fehler geben“, dann wiederhole ich einfach eine Aussage eines Dritten, ohne diese weiter zu bewerten.

Wenn ich aber sage „es solle weitere Fehler geben“, dann schwingen [zumindest leichte] Zweifel in meiner Wiedergabe der anderen Aussage mit, deshalb der Konjunktiv.

Answer (score 3):

Eine Bedeutung von *sollen* ist, den **Willen** einer im Satz nicht genannten Person zum Ausdruck zu bringen. Das kann der Sprecher sein, muß es aber nicht. Also beispielsweise:

> Du **sollst** dein Zimmer aufräumen!
>   1. **Ich** will, daß du dein Zimmer aufräumst.
>   2. **Deine Mutter** will, daß du dein Zimmer aufräumst.

In dieser Bedeutung taucht der Konjunktiv I in Zeitungen dort auf, wo er erwartet wird, also in dem, was z.B. die Duden-Grammatik als *Indirektheitskontext* bezeichnet.

> Die Diözese Rottenburg-Stuttgart teilte mit, es **solle** vorerst auf das Händereichen als Friedensgruß verzichtet […] werden.
>
> Deshalb müsse Schluss sein mit pauschalen Stilllegungen, forderte die IHK Nord, die zwölf norddeutsche Industrie- und Handelskammern vertritt. Es **solle** ein norddeutsches Konjunktur- und Maßnahmenpaket geben.

*Sollen* drückt aus, daß es um einen Willen geht. Der Konjunktiv I drückt aus, daß die Zeitung sich den Willen nicht zu eigen macht. In gesprochener Sprache könnte der Indikativ stehen. **Konjunktiv I und *sollen* dienen also unterschiedlichen Funktionen.**

Bei dem Satz des Fragestellers liegt selbstverständlich eine andere Bedeutung von *sollen* vor, die ich als Ausdruck von **Hörensagen** beschreiben würde. Es geht dann nicht um einen Willen, sondern um eine **Behauptung**; der Urheber der Behauptung wird im Satz nicht genannt.

> Die Software **soll** Fehler haben. Das habe ich zumindest gehört.

Mein Sprachgefühl sträubt sich hier gegen den Konjunktiv I. Vielleicht ist er in dieser Bedeutung von *sollen* sogar ausgeschlossen oder jedenfalls sehr selten.

> #Der Mitarbeiter gab an, die Software **solle** weitere Fehler haben.

Man kommt  in Versuchung, den Satz falsch, mit der ersten Bedeutung von *sollen*, zu interpretieren, also als ob es der Wunsch des Mitarbeiters wäre, daß die Software Fehler habe. Daher habe  ich ihn mit # markiert: Der Satz kann die gesuchte Bedeutung des Hörensagens hier nicht haben.

Comment: Ja, "Der Mitarbeiter gab an, die Software habe weitere Fehler." müsste es dann heißen.

Comment: @userunknown: So stimmt es denke ich auch nicht. Was der Mitarbeiter verkündet, ist ja nicht die Erkenntnis, dass die Software definitiv weitere Fehler hat, sondern *auch aus Sicht des Mitarbeiters* Hörensagen davon, dass dort wohl weitere Fehler vorhanden sind. Nichtsdestotrotz würde auch ich den Satz nicht direkt in den Konjunktiv übertragen, sondern würde intuitiv zu einer Formulierung wie "Der Mitarbeiter gab an, dass die Meinung vorherrsche, die Software habe weitere Fehler." tendieren.

Comment: Man könnte *soll* mit anderen Worten hier auch als Hilfsverb ansehen, das epistemische Modalität ausdrückt.

Answer (score 0):

Thorsten hat recht, dass es umgangssprachlich kaum einen Unterschied macht.  Aber technisch gesehen könnte man die indirekten Reden additiv interpretieren:

- A: "Es gibt auch weitere Fehler."
- B: "Laut A soll es weitere Fehler geben."
- C: "B sagte, es solle weitere Fehler geben."

Weiters wird der Konjunktiv bei einem mehr oder weniger wörtlichen Zitat verwendet, wogegen *sollen* auch eine Zusammenfassung geben, oder vom bloßen Hörensagen reden kann, und folglich schwächer ist (was zum "leichten Zweifel", den Thorsten nennt, übergehen kann (a la: "Angeblich soll es weitere Fehler geben").

Comment: "B sagte also, es gäbe weitere Fehler?" Hm. "Also angeblich gibt es weitere Fehler." Das "angeblich" drückt ja hier den Zweifel schon in unmissverständlicher Stärke aus - wozu noch ein "soll"?